Tracking object data to excel (Location, Rotation, etc.) - Blender
I'm doing simulated motion tracking for my research. I am trying to calculate parameters such as velocity, motion path and trajectory, and tortuosity. However, I can't do any analysis with MATLAB or FIJI without the data from Blender. Currently, I’ve been baking meshes to keyframes and manually extracting coordinates data and transforms frame by frame, but it is really tedious, and I’m getting tired of it. I see there is a spreadsheet option but it doesn't give data I'm looking for. Is there a way to export location data from Blender into an Excel sheet? If so how? Thanks!
Attached is an example of what I need.

